# Java Lock explanation

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

I can't understand the following code:

```
   public class Counter {
      private long value;
      private Lock lock;
      public long getAndIncrement() {
       lock.lock();
       try {
        int temp = value;
        value = value + 1;
       } finally {
         lock.unlock();
       }
       return temp;
      }
    }
```

What I can't understand is how Lock is instantiated while it's an interface?
And if it's an anonymous class that implements Lock interface, why I can't see any override of Lock functions (e.g. lock() and unlock() ) ?

In short, the following line really confuses me.

```
  private Lock lock;
```

What is lock here? What is its type?

**Edit:**

Lock is an interface and can't be instantiated. After looking at the constructor:

```
public Counter(){
   lock = new ReentrantLock();
}
```

Now, everything is clear. (Thanks to Bhushan Uniyal )

Comment: Where did you get this example? This code doesn't compile...

Comment: Lock is a interface and you need to provide it implementation of Lock, there are already some classes which provide the implementation of  Lock  , ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock, ReentrantLockReentrant, ReadWriteLock.WriteLock, 
e.g;
`Lock lock = new , ReentrantLockReentrant();`
also you can provide your own implemention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q  how Lock is instantiated while it's an interface?

Lock in an interface, implemented by     `ReentrantLock, ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock, ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`

[From Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and
>   semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized
>   methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.
>
> A ReentrantLock is owned by the thread last successfully locking, but
>   not yet unlocking it. A thread invoking lock will return, successfully
>   acquiring the lock, when the lock is not owned by another thread. The
>   method will return immediately if the current thread already owns the
>   lock. This can be checked using methods isHeldByCurrentThread(), and
>   getHoldCount().
>
> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many
>   threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often
>   much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller
>   variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation.
>   Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of
>   thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may
>   obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are
>   not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the
>   untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will
>   succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.

[lock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock())

> Acquires the lock.
>
> Acquires the lock if it is not held by another thread and returns
>   immediately, setting the lock hold count to one.
>
> If the current thread already holds the lock then the hold count is
>   incremented by one and the method returns immediately.
>
> If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes
>   disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the
>   lock has been acquired, at which time the lock hold count is set to
>   one.

Answer (score 0):

Lock is a interface and you need to provide it implementation of Lock, there are already some classes which provide the implementation of  Lock  , `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock`, `ReentrantLockReentrant`, `ReadWriteLock.WriteLock,` 
e.g;
`Lock lock = new , ReentrantLockReentrant();`
also you can provide your own implementation

```
public class MyLock implements Lock {


    public void lock() {

    }

    public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {

    }

    public boolean tryLock() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return false;
    }

    public void unlock() {

    }

    public Condition newCondition() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A lock is a thread synchronization mechanism like synchronized blocks except

locks can be more sophisticated than Java's synchronized blocks. Locks (and other more advanced synchronization mechanisms) are created using synchronized blocks, so it is not like we can get totally rid of the synchronized keyword.

From Java 5 the package java.util.concurrent.locks contains several lock implementations, so you may not have to implement your own locks. But you will still need to know how to use them, and it can still be useful to know the theory behind their implementation.